# Display of filetype description in Pantheon Files

Tags: pantheon-files

Is it possible to change the way filetypes are displayed in Files columns? I think it would be enough to display JPEG instead of the lengthy full description "Joint Photographers Experts Group (JPEG) image file format". That takes up so much space! [image: Filetype display]

Comment: In the English (UK) locale, at least, it appears as just "JPEG image", so presumably its a translation issue (not done by Pantheon Files).